# Get Ascii Code?

Tags: awk

To retrieve the ascii code of all charterers of column 13th of a file I write this script

```
awk -v ch="'" '{
for (i=1;i<=length(substr($13,6,length($13)));i++)
{cmd = printf \"%d\\n\" \"" ch substr(substr($13,6,length($13)),i,1) "\"" cmd | getline output close(cmd) ;
Number= Number " " output 
}
 print Number ; Number="" 
}' ~/a.test
```

but it doesn't work in the right way! I mean it works fine a while then produces the weird results!?
As an example , for this input (assume it's column 13th)

> CQ:Z:%8%%%%0%%%%9%%%%:%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

I have to get this

> 37 56 37 37 37 37 48 37 37 37 37 57 37 37 37 37 58 37 37 37 37 ...............

But I have this

> 37 56 37 37 37 37 48 48 48 48 48 57 57 57 57 57 58 58 58 58 58 ...............

As you can see first miss-computation appear after character "0" (48 in result).

Do you know which part of my code is responsible for this error ?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
awk '{
    str = substr($13, 6)
    for (i=1; i<=length(str); i++) {
      cmd = "printf %d \42\47" substr(str, i, 1) "\42"    
      cmd | getline output
      close(cmd)
      Number= Number " " output 
    }
   print Number 
   Number="" 
  }' ~/a.test
```

`\42` is `"` and `\47` is `'`, so this runs `printf %d "'${char}"` in the shell for each `${char}`, which triggers evaluation as a C constant with the POSIX extension dictating a numeric value as noted in the final bullet of the [POSIX printf definition's §Extended Description](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html#tag_04_102_13).

N.B. The formatting matters! 
Don't try to *squeeze* the code unless you know exactly what you're doing!

And a pure *awk* solution (I took the *ord/chr* functions directly from the manual):

```
printf '%s\n' 'CQ:Z:%8%%%%0%%%%9%%%%:%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%'|
  awk 'BEGIN { _ord_init() }
    {
      str = substr($0, 6)
      for (i = 0; ++i <= length(str);)
        printf "%s", (ord(substr(str, i, 1)) (i < length(str) ? OFS : ORS))
      }
    func _ord_init(    low, high, i, t) {
      low = sprintf("%c", 7) # BEL is ascii 7
      if (low == "\a") {     # regular ascii
        low = 0
        high = 127
       } 
      else if (sprintf("%c", 128 + 7) == "\a") {
        # ascii, mark parity
        low = 128
        high = 255
        } 
      else {                  # ebcdic(!)
        low = 0
        high = 255
       }

    for (i = low; i <= high; i++) { 
      t = sprintf("%c", i)
      _ord_[t] = i
       }
    }

  func ord(str,    c) {
    # only first character is of interest
    c = substr(str, 1, 1)
    return _ord_[c]
    }

  func chr(c) {
    # force c to be numeric by adding 0
    return sprintf("%c", c + 0)
    }'
```

Comment: It's too bad that AWK (and gawk) don't have this [POSIX `printf(1)` feature](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/printf.html) (see near the end of EXTENDED DESCRIPTION) in its builtin `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
awk -vSQ="'" -vDQ='"' '{args=space="";n=split($13,a,"");for(i=1;i<=n;i++){args=args space DQ SQ a[i] DQ;format=format space "%d";space=" "};format=DQ format "\\n" DQ;system("printf " format " " args)}'
```